# Using node.js HTTP remote client request doesn't return any body

Tags: node.js

I'm using node.js to download a webpage. However, it's not receiving any chunks of data:

```
    console.log('preparing request to ' + url)
    u = require('url').parse(url)
    var remote_client = http.createClient(80, u['host']);
    var request = remote_client.request("GET", u['pathname'], {"host": u['host']});
    console.log("request made")

    request.addListener('response', function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('binary') 
        var body = '';

        response.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
            console.log('chunk received')
        });
    });
```

The last console message is "request made". There are no console messages with "chunk received" or the like. Thoughts?

Comment: you forgot request.end()

Comment: you could also just switch to using http.get()  http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.6/api/http.html#http.get

Comment: Yup you forget request.end(), but I would use a wrapper around this plain library. See https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules => For example [request](http://github.com/mikeal/node-utils/tree/master/request/), [node-wwwdude](http://github.com/pfleidi/node-wwwdude) to name just a few.

Comment: Hello friend i need help how can i upload node.js

Answer (score 12):

This is an example which always worked for me:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    http = require('http');

var connection = http.createClient(8080, 'localhost'),
    request = connection.request('/');

connection.addListener('error', function(connectionException){
    sys.log(connectionException);
});

request.addListener('response', function(response){
    var data = '';

    response.addListener('data', function(chunk){ 
        data += chunk; 
    });
    response.addListener('end', function(){
        // Do something with data.
    });
});

request.end();
```

Comment: deprecated http.createClient from 0.10

Answer (score 1):

You need to call end() on the request to signal that you are ready to send it.  Also you should add a user-agent header to your request. Many web servers look for it.

```
console.log('preparing request to ' + url)
u = require('url').parse(url)
var remote_client = http.createClient(80, u['host']);
var request = remote_client.request("GET", u['pathname'], {"host": u['host'],
                                                           "user-agent": "node.js"});
console.log("request made")

request.addListener('response', function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('binary') 
    var body = '';

    response.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
        console.log('chunk received')
    });
});

request.end();
```